# AJAX get JSON function not looping

Tags: javascript, json, ajax

**Question: Why the function is not able to retrieve the json object?** 
<s>I also noticed when debugging the code on my browser that the console does one pass through the code but never comes back! I thought the way this works is by having the function at the bottom of the html code looping back up until the the request status is changed.</s>

I am starting to learn html javascripting. Following a tutorial I have the following code for html page that gets and parse JSON object:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    function ajax_get_json(){
      //crate our XMLHttpRequestobject
      var hr = new XMLHttpRequest();
      //var p1 = "p1";
      //creat some variable we need to sned to our php file
      hr.open("GET", "mylist.Json", true);
      //set content type information for sending url encoded variables in the
      //reqeust
      console.log(5+6);
      hr.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/json", true);
      //Acess the onreadystatechange event for the XMLHttpRequest object
      hr.onreadystatchange = function(){
        if (hr.readyState == 4 && hr.status == 200){
          var data = JSON.parse(hr.responseText);
          var results = document.getElementsById("results");
          results.innerHTML=data.user;
        //  document.getElementById("results").innerHTML = return_data;
        }
      }
      //send the data to php now and wait for the response to update the
      //status div
      hr.send();
      results.innerHTML = "reqeusting...";
      // document.getElementById("results").innerHTML="processing...";
    }


    </script>
  </head>
<body>
  <div id="results"></div>
  <script type="text/javascript">ajax_get_json();</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Here is the json object code

```
{"user":"John", "age":22, "country":"United States" }
```

Both files are sitting in my ubuntu server that has LAMP enabled. Here is what the directory looks like:

[image]

Comment: It's not related to the problem, but you don't need to set the `Content-type` header, because a `GET` request doesn't send any content. `setRequestHeader()` sets the header for the request, `application/json` is the type of the **response**.

Comment: Get rid of the `Content-type` line.  That's setting the type of the *request* data.  You are not sending any data to the server.

Comment: Your code has a few typos.  `onreadystatchange` isn't an event/function and `resulsts` isn't an element ID.

Comment: Also, what do you mean by "looping"?  There are no loops or anything similar here.  What you are working with is *asynchronous* code.  What that means is that your event/callback will be ran at some point in the future when the AJAX call is done.  There is no looping, the browser will call your function on its own when the call is done.

Comment: oops fixed both typos.

Comment: ok got it so 'hr.onreadystatechange' will be invoked once json object is returned?

Comment: Basically.  `hr.onreadystatechange` sets an *event* which will be triggered for you by the browser once the JSON file is downloaded (once the AJAX call is done).

Comment: Also, does your `mylist.Json` file *actually* have the `;` in it?  If so, remove it.

Comment: It does, and I took it out.  You should also be consistent.  Some of your file names are all lower case but this one is mylist.Json.  Pick a method and stick to it.

Comment: I removed the `;` from `mylist.json`. But getting rid of `Content-type` in `hr.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/json", true);` broke the code. Now it is not getting to the `"requesting..."` message

Answer (score 1):

Apparently the problem lies in declaring `var results` within `hr.onreadystatechange` function. Moving the declaration to the top fixed the code. Here is the working code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <script>
    function ajax_get_json(){
            var results = document.getElementById("results");
      //crate our XMLHttpRequestobject
      var hr = new XMLHttpRequest();
      //var p1 = "p1";
      //creat some variable we need to sned to our php file
      hr.open("GET", "mylist.json", true);
      //set content type information for sending url encoded variables in the
      //reqeust
      //console.log(5+6);
      //hr.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/json", true);
      hr.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/json", true);
      //Acess the onreadystatchange event for the XMLHttpRequest object
      hr.onreadystatechange = function(){
        if (hr.readyState == 4 && hr.status == 200){
          var data = JSON.parse(hr.responseText);
          results.innerHTML=data.user;
        //  document.getElementById("results").innerHTML = return_data;
        }
      }
      //send the data to php now and wait for the response to update the
      //status div
      hr.send(null);
      results.innerHTML = "reqeusting...";
      // document.getElementById("results").innerHTML="processing...";
    }


    </script>
  </head>
<body>
  <div id="results"></div>
  <script>ajax_get_json();</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I expect this is because if `results` is local to the `onreadystatechange` function, then the `results.innerHTML` outside of the function doesn't have a `results` variable to refer to. If you don't do so already, you can [check JavaScript console](http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/8525/how-to-open-the-javascript-console-in-different-browsers) for errors in the future. In this case, it probably would have told you something like `Uncaught ReferenceError: results is not defined`, allowing you to narrow down your debugging efforts.

Comment: Yes sir. That's how I was able to catch the bug. Thanks for the clarification.